# Highcharts bar chart json example?

Tags: highcharts

Can someone point me to a simple highcharts bar chart json example?

Would this be valid input for jason for a basic bar chart?  For some reason it's not rendering.

```
[
   {
      "name":"value1",
      "data":[
         107
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"value2",
      "data":[
         133
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you check if the `xAxis.categories` array have the same lenght as `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic) works for you:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
});
```